# Application at context path /spring-batch-admin-sample-1.2.1.RELEASE could not be started

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am trying to deploy spring-batch-admin-sample-1.2.1.RELEASE.war in tomcat7 but the application is not getting started. Below is the error in log

```
    Mar 19, 2014 11:08:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: Error listenerStart
    Mar 19, 2014 11:08:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: Context [/spring-batch-admin-sample-1.2.1.RELEASE] startup failed due to previous errors
    Mar 19, 2014 11:08:48 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
    SEVERE: The web application [/spring-batch-admin-sample-1.2.1.RELEASE] registered the JDBC driver [org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
    Mar 19, 2014 11:08:48 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
    SEVERE: The web application [/spring-batch-admin-sample-1.2.1.RELEASE] appears to have started a thread

 named [Timer-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```